# polynomial values take on arbitrarily large prime factors?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Let $P$ be an integer valued polynomial with degree $> 1$, is it a theorem that the values $P(n)$ have arbitrarily large prime factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes suppose that all values of $P(n)$ are divisible by the prime numbers $p_1,p_2,...,p_r$ only. Now consider $P(P(0)p_1p_2...p_r)$, if $P(0)$ is different from zero we find that none of the primes $p_1,p_2,...,p_r$ divides $P(P(0)p_1p_2...p_r)/P(0)$.(a contradiction). If $P(0)=0$, then $P(0)$ is divisible by arbitrary large primes.

Comment: [Here](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/some-remarks-on-the-infinitude-of-primes/) is an interesting alternate approach to this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the nice link

Comment: Dear @Amr: I am not sure if your statement "none of the primes $p_1, \dots, p_r$ divides $P(P(0)p_1\dots p_r)$" is true unless you divide by $P(0)$ when $P(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will edit my answer

Comment: why /P(0) and how do you know p_1 doesn't divide that?

Comment: I did not understand. Could you rephrase your question ?